# jQuery custom event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have following code:

```
myCustomMethod(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#element',function(){
        console.log('First call');
    });
});

setTimeout(function(){
    myCustomMethod(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#element',function(){
            console.log('Second call, event first call should be destroyed');
        });
    });
},2000);


function myCustomMethod(funcn){
    funcn();            
}
```

When I test with my browser, I clicked #element console show up `First call`

but after 2 sec I click again it shows

```
First call
Second call, event first call should be destroyed
```

I want to remove the event listener if it is modified  (the part below)

```
Old

$(document).on('click','#element',function(){
    console.log('First call');
});

New

$(document).on('click','#element',function(){
    console.log('Second call, event first call should be destroyed');
});
```

only fires `console.log('Second call, event first call should be destroyed');`

thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding an event handler does not remove previous event handlers, it just adds more, and that's why the old event handler is not removed.

You could use [off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove event handlers in jQuery

```
$(document).on('click.custom', '#element', function(){
    console.log('First call');
});

setTimeout(function(){
    $(document).off('click.custom').on('click.newclick','#element',function(){
        console.log('Second call, event first call should be destroyed');
    });
},2000);
```

to remove all previous handlers for a specific event you'd do

```
$(document).off('click');
```

The function you're using makes no sense at all, and note that you can [namespace events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names) to remove specific events at a later time.

Comment: Then you'd have to remove them, they don't magically dissapear when you attach new ones

Comment: Can I find all handlers which called inside a function?

Comment: As long as they are attached with jQuery's on(), you can use off() to remove them, just read the answer above.

Comment: I mean find `click.custom` and save it to a variable, then use off() to remove it if new handler triggered

Comment: Well, `click.custom` is just a way to namespace, you could do `click.myclick`, `click.santa` or anything else you'd like, it's just so you don't remove all clicks, but only the click that has that name, that way it's easier to manage. If you need to remove all clicks, just use `off('click')`.

Comment: I know, I want to remove only that namespace without removing all clicks, so I want to log all listeners like "click.myclick" inside a function then destroy them when new handler registered